# Find an element which is not in the topology.

Tags: general-topology, order-topology

The order topology is defined on $\{0,1\} \times \mathbb{N}$. Need to find a non-singleton set which is not an element of order topology.

I Choose $A=\{(0,10), (1,1)\}$. How to prove this? Is my choice correct? We need to prove, it cannot be written as union or intersection of basis vectors?

Comment: you haven't specified which total order the set has.

Comment: dictionary order.

Comment: great, what options are there for an intersection of a finite number of "open rays" ?

Comment: can be a finite or infinite set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$A$ is the union of two open intervals $\langle (0,9),(0,11)\rangle$ and $\langle (1,0),(1,2)\rangle$, so is in the order topology.

Observe that any open set in the order topology that contains $(1,0)$ must be infinite though. That should help.

Comment: you mean (1,1)?

Comment: how you assumed $0\in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @MadhanKumar it’s a fact that $0 \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: i get the answer. But $\mathbb{N}$ is set of all natural numbers right?

Comment: @MadhanKumar yes, starting with zero ( see Peano axioms, set theory etc).